# codenameone Open Form by SMS

Tags: authentication, java-me, lwuit, codenameone

I've create some forms in my codenameone application.
This app use SMS to communicate with its server to pass and get data.

I wanna open specific form when specific SMS comes. In every SMS I put a command to open form in mobile device.

Suppose I wanna login:

1. Send Login command from Device to Server.
2. Authenticate from server and send Login command to device.
3. Receive SMS and process what should it display: Display Error or Open another Form.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't intercept SMS's on devices in Codename One, that API isn't available and isn't possible on some platforms (e.g. iOS). You can connect to the server and do everything else using the `ConnectionRequest` class.

Comment: I want to do this just in j2me. What can I do?

Is ConnectionRequest work for SMS?

Comment: I check ConnectionRequest class. It just good for HTTP/HTTPS servers not for APNS.

Comment: If you are only interested in J2ME then just use a native call, see the native section in the developer guide.